# Как распаковать zip архив с паролем с помощью Python

Tags: python

Дано : архив 1.zip с паролем fun, файл в архиве 1.bat.
При попытке выполнения кода

```
    import zipfile
    z=zipfile.ZipFile(r'1.zip','r')
    z.extract('1.bat','./',b'fun')
    z.close()
```

Появляется ошибка

```
RuntimeError: Bad password for file <ZipInfo filename='1.bat' compress_type=99 external_attr=0x20 file_size=41 compress_size=65>
```

Пароль правильный, проверял несколько раз.

Comment: Способ шифрования AES, угадал? Когда тестировал ваш код, у меня проблем не было с архивом, чей способ шифрования был ZipCrypto, а вот на AES-256 ошибка как у вас :) Пароль тот же

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265643/unable-to-extract-encrypted-zip-file-in-python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553150/python-unzip-aes-128-encrypted-file