# Как можно создать zipfile с паролем, и архивировать туда папку

Tags: python, zip

И так, у меня есть патч

```
paths = {"Root": os.getenv("APPDATA") + f"\\nuk.incorporation"}
```

и содержимое этой папки нужно архивировать (там есть подпапки их тоже нужно), но как на архив поставить пароль?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @Духсообщества это не проблема, а вопрос

Comment: для связки: [обратная задача](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1062168/178576)

Comment: @boostyoiu это же бот был, ты написал сообщение для бота )

Comment: @boostyoiu всм?